# Change timestamp variable format or do replacement

Tags: datetime, gitlab, cicd, text-formatting

I am currently working on setting up ci/cd pipeline for pushing nuget packages.

I want to use the built-in CI_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP for version suffix however its ISO 8601 format is not valid for this.

Example ISO 8601 (UTC): 2022-03-15T18:34:43Z

Will need to at least replace colon.

Is it possible to format it differently or do some sort of text replacement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change how the variable is presented, but you can reformat the value in your job.

The unix `date` command can do this. For example, you can declare any valid format as the desired output format.

```yaml
MY_JOB:
  variables:
    DESIRED_FORMAT: "%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S"
  script:
    - nuget_format="$(date -d "$CI_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP" +"$DESIRED_FORMAT")"
    - echo "$nuget_format"
```

This will have an output like:

```
2022-03-15T23-43-17
```

An alternative may be to use `sed` to replace the occurrences of `:` with `-`.

```yaml
script:
  - nuget_time_format="$(sed "s/:/-/g" <<< $CI_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP)"
  - echo "$nuget_time_format"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is exactly what I need!